# Can I detect the user opening developer tools in IE8-9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events

Is there some kind of event I could hook into to detect when the user opens up the developer tools? Currently I setInterval around the problem with

```
var interval, consoleOpen = false;
interval = setInterval(function() {
    if(typeof console !== 'undefined' && typeof console.log !== 'undefined') {
        clearInterval(interval);
        consoleOpen = true;
        console.log("Console is open!");
        // dump debug message queue...
    }
}, 100);
```

but I want to avoid solutions like that if I can, so is there any nicer method that I could use? The reason is to keep a backlog of debug messages and `console.log()` them as soon as a console is present. I already store the messages in an array that works like a queue limited to 100 messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may well not work in IE8 (`defineProperty` is [somewhat buggy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Internet_Explorer_8_specific_case)), but I don't have that to hand to verify the situation. However, it works fine in IE9 [1].

(Appreciate this makes in a not-entirely complete solution, but it might be a useful starting point.)

```
(function() {
    if ('console' in window) return;
    if (!Object.defineProperty) return;

    Object.defineProperty(window, 'console', {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        set: function (val) {
            delete this.console; // 'Unwatch' console changes
            this.console = val;

            // Notify your logging service that it can start
            // outputting to `console.log` here
            // Logger.start() or whatever's appropriate
        }
    });
})();
```

[1] Caveat: I've not actually tested it beyond throwing it at IE to see what happens.